# How many solutions for this question using group by?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, max

I have a table:

```
create table mmm (day int, week int, sales_event int);
insert into mmm (day, week, sales_event) values (6,1,1), (7,1,1), (13,2,0), (14,2,1), (20,3,0), (21,3,0);
```

And I wanna get a result-set that is grouped by week showing two columns. One is week and another one is sales_event. If sales_event includes 1 after group by, then the sales_event is 1, or the sales_event is 0.

This is my solution:

```
select week, if(max(sales_event) = 1, 1, 0) as sales_event
from mmm
group by week;
```

And I wanna know more solutions for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is the way to go here. I would, however, suggest moving the conditional expression *within* the aggregate function:

```
select week, max(sales_event = 1) as sales_event
from mmm
group by week;
```

Not only is this query a bit shorter, but also it would properly handle the case where `sales_event` has values other than `0` or `1`. If, for a given week values `1` *and* `2` were present in that column, then your query would give `0` in the second column (since `max(sales_event)` would return `2`), while you presumably still want `1` (because `1` is available for that week).